# Django filter using two conditions

Tags: python, django, date, django-models, django-filter

I am developing a web app using django. Among with other tables, I have a table called GeneralContract, which has issueDate and Expiration Date as date fields.

I want to find out the profit of an insurance agent in my case would get from these contracts between a period. For example, if the date range is 15 January 2015 - 25 February 2015 I would like to filter all GeneralContract objects who are issued ANY year between this period. 
(i.e. `issueDate__month = Date1.month AND IssueDate.day_gte= Date1.day) AND (IssueDate__month = Date2.month AND IssueDate.day_lte = Date2.day)` ??

I tried the following but it is not giving me the results I wanted and I am not sure if I am writing this in the correct syntax or if my logic is wrong.

```
criterion1 = Q(issuedate__month=date1.month)
criterion2 = Q(issuedate__day__gte=date1.day)
criterion3 = Q(issuedate__month=date2.month)
criterion4 = Q(issuedate__day__lte=date2.day)
criterionA = criterion1 & criterion2
criterionB = criterion3 & criterion4
criterionC = criterionA & criterionB
currentGenProfits = GeneralContract.objects.filter(criterionC, cancelled=False)
```

Is this the right way of doing this filtering logic?

Comment: check the query generated by the django orm. You can get some hints.
`print(currentGenProfits.query)`

Comment: Thank you I'll check that out. Do you think this the right way of querying to get entries between a range of dates of any years though?

Comment: What do you mean by any year between this period, it is unclear. Could you put in relevant data example cases in. Also note this written code has no much sense :).

Comment: @Iklinac Here are some examples:Let's say the period is 25/2/16 - 25/3/16, I would want: entries between 25/2/16-25/3/16  and 25/2/15-25/3/15 and 25/2/14-25/3/14 and so on and so forth...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do that because if date1.day = 5 and date2.day = 4 you will have no result, you must check the month and the date together, syntax is right but logic is wrong.

I may suggest to start by taking the biggest set and then apply filtering on it

Start with filtering between the two month and then remove from the queryset objects which are on the first month but before the min day and remove from the queryset objects which are on the last month but after the max day, i think that can do the job.

Comment: This is what I was trying to write. If you read my written example I am trying to check the month together with the date, but I don't know how to syntax to make this logic.

Comment: No problem ! Please accept the answer if this solved your problem.